# Magento - Automatically redirect to one of the configured payment gateways

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

We want to integrate Paypal and Authorize.net payment gateways into Magento.
Can we do like just take Credit/Debit card details from customer and redirect to one of those gateways automatically for further process ?

User will not select either to go with Paypal or Authorize.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just take the credit card info and then forward to a provider of your discretion.

First of all, PayPal does no longer allow payment without registration (at least in quite some important countries like Germany). Second, you would need to do PCI certification, which is very expensive and time consuming (because you process the credit card data on your servers).

Technically, it would probably be feasible, but you would most likely have to heavily extend or hack Magento.